# How to create Rails query that (I think) requires PostgreSQL subquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Not sure how to do this so title may not be correct.

Each `User` has a field `country` of type String.

Given an array of user_id, country tuples ***for the query***, find all the records that match. Each User must be found with it's own country.

For example, here is the array of tuples.

```
[1, 'us'],
[2, 'mexico'],
[3, 'us']
```

This would return `User` 1 if it exists and its country is `'us'`.
It should also return `User` 2 if it exists and its country is `'mexico'`.

The query should return all matching results.

Rails 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.query_from_tuples(array_of_tuples)
    array_of_tuples.inject(nil) do |scope, (id, country)|
      if scope
        scope.or(where(id: id, country: country))
      else
        where(id: id, country: country) # this handles the initial iteration
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
WHERE (("users"."id" = $1 AND "users"."country" = $2 OR "users"."id" = $3 AND "users"."country" = $4) OR "users"."id" = $5 AND "users"."country" = $6) 
LIMIT $7
```

You could also adapt kamakazis `WHERE (columns) IN (values)` query by:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.query_from_tuples_2(array_of_tuples)
    # just a string of (?,?) SQL placeholders for the tuple values
    placeholders = Array.new(array_of_tuples.length, '(?,?)').join(',')
    # * is the splat operator and turns the tuples (flattened) into
    # a list of arguments used to fill the placeholders
    self.where("(id, country) IN (#{placeholders})", *array_of_tuples.flatten)
  end
end
```

Which results in the following query which is a lot less verbose:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
WHERE ((id, country) IN ((1,'us'),(2,'mexico'),(3,'us'))) LIMIT $1
```

And can also perform much better if you have a compound index on [id, country].

Answer (score 1):

I know this would work in pure SQL: e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE (id, country) IN ((1, 'us'), (2, 'mexico'), (3, 'us'))
```

Now I don't know how Rails would handle the bind parameter if it was a list of pairs (list of two elements each). Perhaps that would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a raw sql and use active record. Something like this:

```
def self.for_multiple_lp(arr=[])
  # Handle case when arr is not in the expected format.
  condition = arr.collect{|a| "(user_id = #{a[0]} AND country = #{a[1]})"}.join(" OR ")
  where(condition)
end
```

**Edit: Improved Solution**

```
def self.for_multiple_lp(arr=[])
  # Handle case when arr is not in the expected format.
  condition = arr.collect{|a| "(user_id = ? AND country = ?)"}.join(" OR ")
  where(condition, *(arr.flatten))
end
```

This should work.

Comment: I think this should actually work. Thank you! You may want to remove the first answer because it allows for SQL injection.